# Problem in marrying a bohra girl

Tags: sharia, islamic-basis, bohra

I am hindu. My girl friend is Bohra from Udaipur, India. We have a relation of 4 years. We asked her parents for our marriage. Following is their response "As per quoran- A bohra man can marry hindu girl but a hindu man can never marry a bohra girl". They are forcing the girl to marry a bohra boy. How can i marry her? Also if whatever they are saying is correct then this rule seems to be wrong.

Comment: No non Muslim man can not marry Muslim woman. If you will marry her she will not be considered Muslim.

Comment: @Xitas your second sentence is not true. Sins don't expel you from Islam - this is a deviant Mu`tazili belief.

Comment: @ Down voters. please write the reason for down voting. Your votes tells about your thinking.

Comment: @Ansari I wrote "I don't consider them Muslim" but you are right.It not about my view its about Islam.

Comment: According to that question (and several of its duplicates), her parents are correct. What you can do is either 1) disregard Islamic law, 2) respect Islamic law by not marrying her, or 3) become a Muslim.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude I am ready to accept point 1 and 2. But I dont want to be Muslim and terror for the world. So I sont want to accept point 3

Comment: @SunilKumarSahoo What you do is your own business. Beyond the information you've just been given, this site's function as an academic Q&A has served its purpose for your question. I sympathize with your problem, but if you're having trouble deciding what to do, strangers on the internet are not your best recourse. You need to talk this out with a trusted friend or two.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude I hope you got best answer about your suggestions. Sometimes strangers are best resource and thats why we take others help to get right opinion.

Comment: Considering the reaction of the family, it is partially contrary to the Quran: as a muslim man, you could marry their daughter, but their problem wasn't that you aren't muslim, but that you aren't a Bohra. They want a Bohra husband for their daughter, if you would be a muslim (but not a Bohra) you had been probably also rejected on this reason. But maybe being a good programmer, a change to the muslim faith would make you maybe enough good party for their family to accept you.

Answer (score 1):

As per Islam they are correct in not allowing you to marry her, although they are wrong in saying a (Muslim) 'Bohra' man may marry a Hindu girl. Perhaps in their cultural 'Bohra' customs this is acceptable, however Islam only permits its male adherents from marrying *People of The Book (′Ahl al-Kitāb)*. *People of The Book* refers to Muslim, Jewish, and Christian women. On the other hand, **Muslim women are only permitted to marry Muslim men**.

The only way to make this marriage acceptable according to the religion of your girlfriend would be for you to sincerely convert to Islam.

Granted, this may not change the opinions of your girlfriend's family, nor bode well with their cultural norms. That will be up to you to work through. But from an Islamic perspective, if you become a Muslim, then her family would have to come up with a very good reason to prevent her from marrying you (e.g. dificiencies in your character).

I would also like to add that Islam forbids parents from forcing a marriage upon their children. So from the perspective of their religion (Islam), they should not be forcing her to marry a specific person.

I wish you both the best of luck, and hope this answers your quesion.

Comment: Bohra is an Islamic school of belief not a culture. And maybe what they are saying is by their Islamic rules. Another way would be that the girl converts to Hinduism.

Comment: 'Bohras' are a community of people in the India region. There is not a set religious position amongst the Bohras. To my limited knowledge, they were originally Ismaili Shia, although some branches have converted to Sunni Islam. What I was saying is according to the most basic, 'orthodox' Islamic rules.. something that I'm sure both mainsteam 'Sunni' and 'Shia' clerics would agree with.

Comment: [Dawoodi Bohra \[...\] are a sub-sect of Shia Islam.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawoodi_Bohra)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to take something called a Misaq, which is basically an oath. You would then be able to marry her. As a Bohra, many people that I know, have married outside of the religious sect. A family friend of mine married a Hindu man. He is now a very practicing Bohra... he did convert though (and take the oath).

Bohra Islam is quite different from mainstream Islam/Shiaism. It's more of a culture and a distinct community that also follows a variation of Islam. If you speak Gujurati (the language in which we communicate, it would be really beneficial to you). You would fit right in, and also understand our holiness. It's a straightforward religion/culture. If you're set on marrying her, then take the misaq (it's a ceremony with the Aamil).

Best of luck!

Comment: I respect Islam. I ll think about Misaq, if section 47:4, 8:12 (which is root cause of terrorism) is removed from Quran. Till those sections exist. I cant accept as I dont want to be a terrorists.

Answer (score -1):

there is point of view that muslim person may marry any monotheist religion person:

> ... And do not marry (you women) the ‘mushrikeen’ until they believe
>   ... The word ‘shirk’ is used consistently in the Quran to mean the act
>   of setting partner/s with God in any of God's exclusive rights ...

- http://www.quran-islam.org/articles/quranic_law_for_marriage_%28P1165%29.html

but hindu are not monotheistic probably.

i also suggest to embrace islam.

i have found a strong counter-argument to the above prooflink text: http://quran.com/60/10 : ... And if you know them to be believers, then do not return them to the disbelievers ("alkuffar"); they are not lawful [wives] for them, nor are they lawful [husbands] for them. ... and as far as i know, christians and jews are accounted as disbelievers in quran.

Comment: Hindus are monotheistic. and we worship all forms of same god

Comment: I was ready to accept islam although her family and community never accepted me and scold me for my religion. I never accept any wrong things. I dont like only take policy. I believe in Give and Take policy. So I will never embrace islam.